# can not align an imageview to a viewpager

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager

i'm working on an android project.

i have an viewpager and i want to have to imageView right and left side of that and when the user click on them, viewpager go to next page or previous page.

i try to align left and right two imageview around my viewpager but it doesn't come to right of that and come under the viewpager

you can see my layout code below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/level_selector_levels_list"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/level_selector_levels_list"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/level_selector_values_main_page_view_pager_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/level_selector_values_main_page_view_pager_top_bottom_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/level_selector_values_main_page_view_pager_left_right_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/level_selector_values_main_page_view_pager_left_right_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/level_selector_values_main_page_view_pager_top_bottom_margin" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Second, i don't see second imageview in your layout. Add similar like first one with:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/level_selector_levels_list".
```

So, complete code would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/level_selector_levels_list"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ne2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/level_selector_levels_list"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />    

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/level_selector_levels_list"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/level_selector_values_main_page_view_pager_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"        
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/level_selector_values_main_page_view_pager_top_bottom_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/level_selector_values_main_page_view_pager_left_right_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/level_selector_values_main_page_view_pager_left_right_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/level_selector_values_main_page_view_pager_top_bottom_margin" />

</RelativeLayout>
```